# How do I add e-mail subscription functionality

Tags: functions

Hi I am new to wordpress. Kinda going through different themes that is available. I like on, which is [Oulipo](http://theme.wordpress.com/themes/oulipo/), but it doesn't have any e-mail subscription feature. I am using free wordpress hosting.

I know may be this question is too silly but I don't understand how to add it. As I have heard free word press hosting don't have many features available, so I was wondering if only the allowed features are those that comes with the theme or is it customizable further?

Thanks.

Comment: Is your site on wordpress.com, or are you referring to a free webhost(not wordpress.com)?

Comment: Yes, I am referring to site wordpress.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many plugins currently available allow you to enable this feature on your site. My favorite is [Jetpack Subscriptions](http://jetpack.me/support/subscriptions/) for reasons including:

- Very much up-to-date, well-maintained plugin
- Emails sent from WordPress.com servers, so there's absolutely no load on your servers

(Make sure you disable all the unnecessary modules activated by default when you activate [Jetpack by WordPress.com plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/jetpack/).)

If you want the emails to be sent from your servers, I think you'd be better off using [Subscribe to Comments](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/subscribe-to-comments/) or [Subscribe To Comments Reloaded](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/subscribe-to-comments-reloaded/)—whichever suits you best.

Answer (score 0):

If the User is on WordPress.com then they will need to setup subscriptions using the WordPress Hosted tools.  Plugins and extensions like Jetpack are not possible.

You can create a Widget for your theme sidebar in WordPress.com and have a link to your email subscription form.

Mailchimp is my preferred free option and they have a [Guide](http://kb.mailchimp.com/article/how-to-add-a-mailchimp-signup-form-to-your-wordpress-blog/) which is easy to follow.

Answer (score 0):

My favourite is [MailOptin plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/mailoptin/). You can use it to add an optin form before and after your post or page, at your website sidebar using its widget and even a popup optin form.

FWIW it does have a premium version with lots of other features you might find interest such as [exit intent](https://mailoptin.io/demos/exit-intent/) and [scroll trigger](https://mailoptin.io/demos/scroll-trigger/) which I think is value for money